# Choose Java 7 JRE to run App Engine Dev Server with Cloud Tools for Eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-eclipse-plugin

I try to run my maven App Engine project using Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse. Using "Run As > App Engine" as suggested in [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/running-and-debugging) results in the project being run in a Java 8 runtime (same as Eclipse uses). App Engine only supports Java 7. The only execution environment in the Eclipse installation is a Java 7 JRE.

How can I make the Dev Server use the Java 7 JRE?

**Edit**

Upgrading to Cloud Tools for Eclipse 1.1 did the trick; it now looks for the JVM that is configured for the project.

Answer (score 0):

1. First check if you have Java 7 installed on your system and environment variable are set correctly
2. Now coming to the Eclipse, `Right Click On Your Project -> Java Compiler -> Set Compiler Compliance Level to 1.7`
3. You can apply this setting for all the future projects by doing this `'Window'  Menu -> Java -> Compiler -> Set Compiler Compliance Level to 1.7`

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Which environment variable? Setting JAVA_HOME to the Java 7 JDK was no use; it seems the server uses the same JRE as eclipse instead of the JRE configured in Eclipse preferences.